# VMware Distributed Switch Traffic Filtering and Marking DEFAULT RULE

Tags: networking, esxi

I haven't found a solid answer anywhere about what the Distributed Switch Traffic Filtering default rule is. Like you know when you make an ACL on a Cisco switch and it has an implicit deny at the end of it... Whether or not you tell it to, if there is not something above there which allows the traffic through it is going to be denied. Well I can't figure out what VMware does by default.

See for my situation I need to use the Markings feature to edit DSCP values on packets leaving the VMware environment. Unfortunately VMware has tied the Markings and Filtering into the same feature. So the worry is that I enable feature, and only put in one rule (for example) which says to change the DSCP value on all packets from subnet X.X.X.X for SNMP traffic (say for example). And then because I have no allow/deny statements, does it hit a default deny any, and yeah... My traffic got marked, right before it got dropped.

To be clear and concise:
What happens to traffic which runs through the Marking and Filtering feature on VMware Distributed Switches by default (if no rule is matched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with VMware they said the default action is Allow ALL. So if you don't have an express deny statement for traffic, or if it evaluates a packet and reaches the bottom of the list without a match, the default action is to allow the traffic in case anyone else is looking.

Comment: Usually, normal, hardware switches tend to have a default (implicit!) _deny_ at the end of ACLs, so in if that was the case for the distributed virtual switch as well and you would turn on filtering on a port group, you might seriously harm your existing infrastructure as you would drop all traffic that wouldn't have any explicit allow statement. Thank you for finding out about the default _allow_.